# About wait() and notify() methods of thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I know the mechanism of `wait()` and `notify()` of thread, but I am unable to understand that why `wait()` and `notify()` methods should be in `synchronized` block? Is this mandatory?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I will give a deep so not-obvious but relatively short explanation: the threads that `wait` and ca notified must be stored in some shared structure[queue or stack]. Modifying the structure alone will require locking. While it's s possible to impl. lock-free stack/queue, it will have no guarantees that a waiting thread will be awaken properly, i.e. awakening can happen before the thread goes to sleep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Is synchronized mandatory while invoking wait/notify**: Yes
2. **Why?**: Consider that synchronizing was not required. That means that a thread A could call notify() exactly at the same time while the other thread B is calling wait()(on the same object). Suppose thread B has executed part of **wait()** method and is context-switched to serve thread A. So the internal data-structures of wait could be in corrupt state now. Now the **notify()** method essentially works on the same data-structures, which now is in invalid state. Hence the entire wait/notify could go for a toss. Synchronizing guarantees that no other method could call wait/notify if there is a call to one of them already on.

Comment: as far as I understood javadoc these internal shared data structures are called wait sets. During the `wait()` call it is necessary to place current thread into this wait set and during `notify(All)()` it is necessary to remove threads from the object's wait set. Am I correct?

Comment: I am afraid, this answer doesn't clear up the misconception, OP is having. Which is, precisely, `wait()` and `notify()` are not the members of `Thread` class. Please care to update your answer to clarify the thing.

Comment: @Adeel The OP's doubt is as to why is synchronization enforced on wait/notify calls

Comment: @Alex Look, the internal datastructures of monitors depend on JVM implementation. So what you say may be true for Sun(Oracle?) JVM, but may not be true for other JVMs